# Paramiko module using python for a long time without operation causes SSHException: Server connection dropped error

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko

I tried to use flask and paramiko to display some log information to the browser, and now I can display the log message to the browser. However, if flask is not operated for a long time, an error will be reported --paramiko.ssh_exception.Can you provide some ways to keep SSH connected?

I tried adding a timeout parameter, but it didn't work

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(host['host_124']['hostname'], host['host_124']['port'],host['host_124']['username'], host['host_124']['password'],compress=True, timeout='65536')
sftp_client = client.open_sftp()
```

I want to keep SSH connected all the time, but now I get an error in 2 minutes.

Comment: Handle the exception and reconnect.

Comment: Is there any way to keep SSH talking back all the time? :)